# Getting Ruby NET::SCP or NET::SFTP to use different ciphers

Tags: ruby, capistrano, scp, net-sftp

I am trying to force Capistrano v2 to use an arcfour cipher on uploading.

Snippet from a function overloading upload:

```
puts "Implementing rsync deploy"
servers = find_servers_for_task(current_task)
upload(from,to,options.merge(:hosts => servers[0].host).merge(:encryption => 'arcfour'), &block)
```

Capistrano allows other options to pass through to the underlying implementation libraries of NET::SCP and NET::SFTP, if anyone has an example of forcing either of those libraries to use a different cipher, or of capistrano using a different cipher - that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was this:

set :ssh_options, { :encryption => "blowfish-cbc" }